# How to extend a partially unknown query with a filter in SqlAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

With a "partially unknown query", I mean a query which is composed of sub-queries where the original SqlAlchemy sub-query objects are not available / not known to the entity that is working with the query.

Consider the following example: I have a function that produces some query that contains sub-queries, which serves as a basis for specialized queries. An example of such a function could look like this:

```
def get_base_query(user_id: int) -> Query:
    max_reps = get_max_reps_query().subquery()
    user_reps = get_user_reps_query(user_id).subquery()
    return (
        session
        .query(
            max_reps.c.topic.label('topic'),
            (max_reps.c.reps - user_reps.c.reps).label('reps'),
        )
        .select_from(
            max_reps.join(user_reps, max_reps.c.topic == user_reps.c.topic)
        )
    )
```

Some other function is going to receive that `Query` object and wants to extend it. This function only knows the the structure of the input query result (i.e. two columns `topic` and `reps`). Say this function needs to extend the query in a way to limit the rows to match a certain `topic`.

I've tried the following ways to achieve this, but the behavior is as outlined in the comments below:

```
from sqlalchemy import func as F

def query_filter_topic(query: Query, topic: str) -> Query:  
    # Doesn't actually filter the rows.
    query = query.filter(Exercise.topic == topic)  

    # Doesn't actually filter the rows.
    query = query.filter(query.subquery().c.topic == topic)  

    # Results in 0 rows.
    query = query.filter(F.topic == topic)  

    ...
```

My hypothesis is that none of these column references match any of the columns of the outer-most SELECT of the query (because they are dynamically created columns). I was really expecting the `subquery().c.exercise_name` bit to work.

Is there a "correct" way to extend the query? Given that I explicitly labeled the columns in `get_base_query()`, I feel like there should be a way to reference those columns.

> *On a side note, I would expect SqlAlchemy to throw an error rather than silently accepting these columns that it apparently can't process. The `filter()` calls that doesn't filter rows doesn't seem to change the `Query` object at all (judging by the `str()` representation).*

The only way I could figure out to get it working is the below, but it doesn't feel like the right way to do it.

```
def query_filter_topic(query: Query, topic: str) -> Query:
    query = query.subquery()
    query = session.query(*query.c).filter(query.c.topic == topic)
```